# the rust equivalent of this python code does not work?

Tags: python, web-scraping, rust, request, encode

i have a code that gets html body of a website in python that routes through tor.
this is the code in python:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
                    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'}
r = session.get("https://einthusan.tv/movie/results/?lang=kannada&query=love")
print(r.text)
```

and this is the rust code i wrote:

```
use std::fs;
use reqwest::blocking::Client;
fn main() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let proxy = reqwest::Proxy::all("socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050").expect("error connecting to tor!");
    let client = Client::builder().proxy(proxy).build()?;
    
    let formatted_url = format!("https://einthusan.tv/movie/results/?lang=malayalam&query=premam");
    
    let response = client
        .get(&formatted_url)
        .send()?;

    // Read and print the response body
    let body = response.text()?;
    println!("{}", &body);
    fs::write("response.txt", &body);

    Ok(())
}
```

. By python, i can get the html body. But, by rust, [i am getting some encoded like this](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/iv9Pd2O4). How to resolve this?

I have tried putting headers that accept "text/html" or "charset=utf-8" and no help. I am still getting the encoded text.

Comment: What's in your Cargo.toml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response from that website is gzip encoded (header `Content-Encoding: gzip`), which is why the content looks garbled. In the python version using `requests`, the response is automatically gzip decoded.

To automatically decode gzip using `reqwest` in rust, you need to enable the `gzip` feature.

See [`ClientBuilder::gzip()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html#method.gzip) for more information